# mediaelement.js How implement preroll vast tags?

Tags: mediaelement.js, vast

I saw that in version 2.11.0 (2012/03/13) added Preroll ads manager and VAST ads plugin; but i only found examples for implemement postroll.
Where is the doc for this features or what is the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old, but I too have been looking to do preroll with mediaelement. I came across this: http://mediaelementjs.com/tests/mep-vast.html

Hopefully this will help future people looking to implement this.

Comment: How does this work exactly? I can see the working example, but where is some code to work off of? And of course it's not included in the media element .zip downloaded from the site.

Comment: nevermind, inspecting the source code and viewing mep-feature-ads-vast.js seemed to answer my question!